# Suggestions for code provide reading QR code with camera works on desktop(not mobile)

Tags: javascript, java, applet, qr-code, desktop

I need to read QR code with camera on desktop (not mobile) but that is not applet.(Why can not I choose applet so chrome will withdraw its support).I prefer java or javascript code.

help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what Google gave me -

1. [Open Source QR Code Library](http://qrcode.osdn.jp/index.html.en) That seems to be the name. GPL licensed and has integration with Java
2. [ZBar bar code reader](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) supports QR code. has the more flexible LGPL license but seems to have API support only for Python, Perl, C++?

Answer (score 0):

Some libraries that may help

https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/

https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode

Comment: camera field does not appear so "capture" button doest not work

Comment: On which of the two suggestions, I'm curious?

Answer (score 0):

[read qrcode with camera what work on js](http://atandrastoth.co.uk/main/pages/plugins/codereader/)